# Tools/methods to extract math expressions from plain unstructured text

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, named-entity-recognition

I need to identify math expressions embedded in text. For example "Write down the value of A + B." Here 'A + B' is the part I need to extract and it is not expressed using any structured text like Latex, but in plain unstructured text.

Are there any tools/methods to extract such expressions in text, like a POS tagger or a Name Entity recognition tool for math expressions?

First I tried to do this using regular expressions, but that is not successful for complex expressions. I found many research papers to extract math expressions from scanned documents ( from an image) or from structured text, but I found nothing for plain text.

Comment: Can you provide regular expressions that you used and where it's failed?

Comment: My exact requirement is to extract expressions of the type 'n(A∩B) = 10'. I used the regex 'n(\([\w\' ]*∪*∩*\\*[\w\' ]*\))[ ]*=[ ]*\d+' . But I cannot handle more complex expressions such as 'n(A∩(C∩D∩E)∪(B∩F)) = 10' in a general way using regex.